# Get elasticsearch indices before specific date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My logstash service sends the logs to elasticsearch as daily indices.

```
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "127.0.0.1:9200" ]
    index => "%{type}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
}
```

Does Elasticsearch provides the API to lookup the indices before specific date?

For example, how could I get the indices created before `2015-12-15` ?

Comment: Do you want to query data that exists in indexes before a given date, or receive a list of indexes that are named before a given date?

Comment: `receive a list of indexes that are named before a given date`  Yes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `Indices Query` have a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-indices-query.html)

Here is an example:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "indices" : {
            "query": {
                "term": {"description": "*"}
            }, 
            "indices" : ["2015-01-*", "2015-12-*"],
            "no_match_query": "none"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No.  I want to search the index itself. instead of the index content.  The index name actually is unknown to me and it is something to be search

Comment: By using `Indices Query` you may write a wildcard expression of your index as I have updated in the example. This is by no means a good solution but it works for some extent. Thinking about it again, why do you need indexes created before a specific date? Is it the content which you are looking for? If that is so, all content you have indexed in a specific date can be queried by filtering according to date etc. Then you'll get all data indexed in a date range of your choice which will include all indexes as you wanted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I really care about what indexes are created is when I want to close/delete them using curator.  Curator has "age" type features built in, if that's also your use case.

Comment: Sounds like what I need. Do you like more details how curator works with indexes created by logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Each index has a [creation_date](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html#_creation_date) field.

Since the number of indices is supposed to be quite small there's no such feature as 'searching for indices'. So you just get their metadata and filter them inside your app. The creation_date is [also available](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11688) via [_cat API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html).